# How to setup a CRON JOB in MAGENTO?

Tags: php, magento, import, automation, cron

I want to setup a **CRON JOB** in Magento.
My requiremen-: In our shop which is built in Magento, **Customers,products & tier prices** are coming in .csv file which we manually importing till the time.

So now we are reading that **.csv file** which is where Magento is placed through **PHP**. We fetch that data in csv file through php & insert data in relevant tables of Magento database.

So for that I made php file which externally connected to Magento db & do the needful task of fetching & inserting data.
Now how to setup **CRON job** so that this process will become automatic...I gone through Magento website where they mention How to setup a cron job?

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job
```

but still have a plenty of doubts...
So can anybody explain me how should I set up cron job so that this sample php file work & our process of fetching & inserting Customer, products, Pricing etc. become **automatic**?

**Plz provide me basic info. on how to setup cron job in Magento for above scenario or can we use CRON job created with the help of PHP?**

```
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/
```

If anyone have sample code for the same that will really help me alot...

plz guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's nothing specify related to Magento, which is just another php script. just set up the cron to run the appropriate script from the command line

php /path to script/script.php

Comment: Actually I don't know what exactly I need to do for this...:( I am very new to this CRON concept...Can u plz explain more...

Answer (score 1):

Setting a cron in magento can be done by opening the cron tab for editing and then specifying the path :-

`*/10 * * * * php -q /path/to/magento/cron.php`

It will run your cron every 10 minutes.

You can check the magento admin as well and change the required thing like log clearing and all.

`System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable making HTTP requests from your PHP scripts on the server, [SaturnAPI](https://saturnapi.com/) has a secure scheduling solution that may be suitable for you. It's a REST API. You make HTTP requests to schedule, view and delete jobs. Below is an example for scheduling a job:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://saturnapi.com/cron/jobs \
    -H saturnapi-access-key:'YOUR_SATURNAPI_ACCESS_KEY' \ 
    -d dateTimeUTC='2015:09:25 14:30' \
    -d dateTimeFormat='YYYY:MM:DD HH:mm' \
    -d callbackURL='https://your.verified.domain.com' \
```

When the time comes, the `callbackURL` will receive an HTTP POST. It's very simple, and there's no need to install anything on your server.

Disclosure: I worked on [SaturnAPI](https://saturnapi.com/)